# Path in proxy_pass in dockerized nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to serve both frontend and backend routing. All is done with use of docker. Here's my nginx config:

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }


  location /auth/ {
    rewrite /auth/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

The thing is that when I'm using in my front requests routes beginning with `/api`it rewrites it but without `/api` part persisted, so it is looking for `/`. How can I work it that to persist `/api` part?

Comment: `proxy_pass http://client$request_uri;`?

Comment: Thank you, the answer is correct.